# Xcode storyboard ViewController is being cut in simulator. Why?

Tags: objective-c

For some reason if i put a button at the bottom of the screen and then run the simulator it wont show. It is almost like it is cutting out the bottom of the view controller. I thought it was something to do with the settings of the simulator but I cant find anything.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Aren't you running iPhone4S simulator? try with iPhone5 and it won't be cut. :)If it works, i will explain whats happening, and how to solve it .

Comment: I haven't checked that thanks. Apparently it's the 6.1 simulator or something like that.

Comment: its just iOS version.. :)

Comment: What do you mean its just the iOS version, is it changeable or can I never change this?

Comment: iOS is operating system on which your apps run, you don't need to change it. While iPhone4S and iPhone5 screen size varies, iPhone4S and earlier got a screen size of 3.5" while 5's screen size s 4", you probably got why things get cut out from screen.